# Gnumeric Nlsolve does nothing

Tags: 15.04, gnumeric

I am attempting to do simple non-linear decision models on my laptop running Ubuntu 15.04; however when I click solve Gnumeric appears to not do anything when I have the "non-linear model" selected. When I solve the window pops up saying it found a "feasible" solution, which is true, but as 1. it does not let me run if the constraints are not initially met and 2. I can manually change the values to improve the solution I can tell it is not a very good solution...

I also tried installing the newest versions (1.12.23 and 1.12.24) following these instructions (http://linuxpitstop.com/install-gnumeric-1-12-23-on-ubuntu-15-04/) however I'm relatively new to Ubuntu and have not had time to update all of the dependencies, on the "./configure" step both versions give me the following unmet dependencies:

#### versions .23 and .24 configuration error

```
configure: error: Package requirements (
    libgoffice-0.10 >= 0.10.22
    libgsf-1        >= 1.14.33
    libxml-2.0      >= 2.4.12

    gtk+-3.0        >= 3.8.7
) were not met:

Requested 'libgoffice-0.10 >= 0.10.22' but version of libGOffice is 0.10.18
Requested 'libgsf-1 >= 1.14.33' but version of libgsf-1 is 1.14.30
```

When I tried to install version 1.12.20 `./configure` appears to work correctly, however when I run "make" I get the following errors:

#### version .20 make error

```
dialog-cell-format.c:1835:4: warning: pointer/integer type mismatch in conditional expression
    : NULL;
    ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
Makefile:746: recipe for target 'dialog-cell-format.lo' failed
make[5]: *** [dialog-cell-format.lo] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/gnumeric-1.12.20/src/dialogs'
Makefile:606: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[4]: *** [all] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/gnumeric-1.12.20/src/dialogs'
Makefile:2330: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/gnumeric-1.12.20/src'
Makefile:1066: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/gnumeric-1.12.20/src'
Makefile:644: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/gnumeric-1.12.20'
Makefile:500: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

#### snapshot of simple non-linear problem attempting to solve

[model set up in gnumeric](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5oza.png)

In solver:

- parameters are: target cell = D5; minimize; by changing cells = F5:H5
- Model: "Non-linear model"
- Constraints are: "C5 >= C7" and "J5 = J7"
- everything else as default

Any ideas for me?

#### Edit: model set up details

Forgot some info for anyone trying to replicate this: active calculations.
So,

- Cell D11 is `=sumproduct($F$5:$H$5,F11:H11)` which can then be copied down through cell D14 (eg D14 is `=sumproduct($F$5:$H$5,F14:H14)`
- Cell C5 is `=average(D11:D14)`
- Cell D5 is `=stdevp(D11:D14)`
- Cell J5 is `=sum(F5:H5)`

Comment: Follow these directions http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/xsoft/gnumeric.html If it fails, come back. Get your dependencies first.

Comment: @j0h, you're probably right - but after some hours on this I just found reference to LibreOffice 5 having been updated and it's solved my immediate need... will put your link and LibreOffice in an answer

Answer (score 0):

As @j0h references for anyone coming across this wanting to stick with Gnumeric here are some straightforward installation instructions: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/xsoft/gnumeric.html

I instead updated to version 5 of LibreOffice and it's non-linear optimization is working perfectly. Instructions here: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2015/08/upgrade-libreoffice-5-0-ubuntu-linux-mint/